# Xcode for C Implementation - Random Generator - Environment Problems

Tags: c, xcode, random

When you have a few files (see below), how do you get them all working inside Xcode for a C implementation?

```
These are the files that I’ve been given for this project: 
pcg_basic.c 
pcg_basic.h 
pcg32-demo.c
```

Project guidelines:
http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c-basic.html

I am also unclear what should be copied to the main.c file. Can't get a grasp on this.

Apparently you also need to link the code with the pcg_basic.o.
(not sure how to do that, either)

I know the code does work because it was developed by an expert in this space. But everything I try in Xcode ("fails to build"), so I presume it must be the way I've set things up.

What am I doing wrong?

*Student here. I am totally new to programming. Thanks!

[error snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSapH.png)

[error snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxDNk.png)

CODE
    /*
     * PCG Random Number Generation for C.
     * For additional information about the PCG random number generation   scheme,
     * including its license and other licensing options, visit
     *     http://www.pcg-random.org
     */

```
/*
 * This file was mechanically generated from tests/check-pcg32.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pcg_basic.h"   <---pcg_basic.h not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup:

- in Xcode <File/New/Project...>
- choose `macOS` template tab
- from there choose `Command Line Tool`
- in the Wizard choose `C` as language

Drag & drop your files (pcg_basic.h, pcg_basic.c, pcg32-demo.c) to the Xcode project navigator on the left where `main.c` resides. A dialog appears: make sure to check `Copy items if needed`. Then delete main.c in Xcode.

The program builds and runs then.

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Despite the fact that appears to be working as it should, the instructions suggest --- I also need to link the code with the pcg_basic.o.  How would that be done? Such a file was not even included.

Comment: When Xcode compiles pcg_basic.c as an intermediate result the .o file is generated. You don't normally need it directly, so I wonder a little bit why you would need it? Anyway, there is normally a folder  `/Users/<yourusername>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and inside there will be something like `random-xxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/random.build/Debug/random.build/Objects-normal/x86_64` where you can find the .o files.

Comment: What lines of code (and where?) would I need to write in the pcg32-demo.c file to save the output into a SQLite db? Thanks. @Stephan Schlecht